# Throwing EntityExistsException programmatically - bad practice?

Tags: java, jpa, exception

I'm using `JPA` and I want to throw an exception when someone is trying to modify existing entity. Can I throw `javax.persistence.EntityExistsException` or should I consider creating my own exception type? What is considered the best practice?

Comment: The documentation reads *"Thrown by the persistence provider when EntityManager.persist(Object) is called and the entity already exists."*. I would consider it being thrown when you are modifying something in existence weird then as it does not fit the description of the exception. I would say it's best practice to use the exception whose description fits the error that happened. Throw an `IllegalArgumentException` when an argument is illegal. Don't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` when someone is accessing a not initialized field in your data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given that [the JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityExistsException.html) explicitly says

> Thrown by the persistence provider when `EntityManager.persist(Object)`
>   is called and the entity already exists

I would say that throwing it under any other situation is misuse.

---

As to whether to create your own exception type, that's opinion-based. I very rarely find any value in doing this unless I need to catch something very specific.

Comment: So you recommend throwing RuntimeException?

Comment: If you don't need to catch it, a `RuntimeException` with an appropriate message is fine. There may be a more appropriate unchecked exception type that you could use, but there's nothing wrong with `RuntimeException` either (IMO)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that what you want to do is optimistic locking to prevent concurrent transaction from updating a single record .

The JPA way of doing it is to add a `@Version` column in that table, then JPA will detect if there are other transaction to update the same record after you retrieve it. If yes , it will throw `OptimisticLockException`. What you need to do is to  catch this exception and determine how to handle it. For example, you can report this situation to the user and let them determine what to do.

Comment: I create REST API. I have two endpoints: POST for creating new user, and PUT for updating existing one. I use Spring data so in both cases I invoke userRepository.save() method. The only thing I want to do is to disable possibility to update a user via POST endpoint.